# How to write the sql join for this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem writing a simple query/join. I assume the query should be possible to write as single query, but I have not succeeded. I have tables and data like below:

**EMPLOYEE**

| empid | name |
| --- | --- |
| joebar | Joe |
| tommyt | Tommy |
| alexia | Alexia |

**JOB**

| jobid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st |
| 2 | 2nd |
| 3 | 3rd |

**JOBRESOURCES**

| empid | jobid | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| joebar | 1 | 21/1/1 |
| tommyt | 1 | 21/1/1 |
| tommyt | 2 | 21/1/3 |
| alexia | 3 | 21/1/4 |

How can I write the logical query "*List all resources and check if they are assigned to job 1?*"

So the result should be:

| empid | jobid |
| --- | --- |
| joebar | 1 |
| tommyt | 1 |
| alexia | (null) |

I have tried:

```
SELECT e.empid, jr.jobid 
FROM employee e 
    LEFT JOIN jobresources jr ON e.empid=jr.empid 
WHERE jr.jobid = 1 
OR jr.empid IS NULL
```

but the row "alexia" is missing. I assumed I can get all rows from employee and "rich" the rows with left join, but it seems not to work.

Comment: Like: `SELECT employee.empid, jobresources.jobid FROM employee LEFT OUTER JOIN jobresources ON employee.empid = jobresources.empid AND jobresources.jobid = 1;`? (Just read your attempt).. I think I have this correct. Just move your WHERE conditions into your `ON` conditions instead. That feels counterintuitive at first, but putting conditions on your left-table in the `WHERE` clause causes your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to become an implicit `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: What's the purpose of table `Job`? Is it relevant to your query - your desired results don't seem to need it?

Comment: JNevill, thats it!  Totally forgot that rule, putting the filter to "ON" part for the left join.